# Omission of "second job"

Tags: resume

I just started a part-time "second job."

I had omitted my previous "second job" from my resume, but I inserted my primary "first job."

Would the above omission be grounds for firing?

Comment: It would only be a problem if they required you to list every job. I have encountered that exactly once - when I applied to UCSD's CS PhD program, I was required to list every job since getting my bachelor's degree.

Comment: If you mean to omit that second job to keep it secretly after starting in a new job, that could in fact lead to legal problems and you being fired.

Answer (score 5):

No. Your CV is accurate.

There is no reason to fire you for not adding all the jobs that you have had.

Answer (score 3):

> Would the above omission be grounds for firing?

No.

You can decide which job(s) to include on your resume and which job(s) to omit.

The only issue might be holding a second job when doing so is against company policy.

Answer (score 3):

No.  A resume is not a sworn statement or a formal job application.  Everyone trims their resume down and tweaks it to show your experience which is relevant to the job you are applying for.

If I am looking at your resume, I do not care about your second job delivering pizza when I'm looking for a systems administrator.  If I saw such a thing, I would wonder why you included it.

Your resume or CV serves one purpose: to show a potential employer that you have the required skills and talents to do the job.

Now, this changes if you are asked to fill out an application, which **is** an official document and you are instructed to list **all** employment.  These days, many applications will say on them "Please list all **relevant** employment, so even formal documents may not care.  I would not worry about this at all.

Answer (score 2):

You won't be fired, the worst that can happen is that your employer loose some trust in you for hiding the information, **depending on the reasons of your omission** (drug use, violence, etc).

If you have been fired for this, omission might get you into trouble.

But if you haven't been fired for these kind of reasons it shouldn't be a problem, just **be ready to have a good explanation** if your new employer finds out.

Comment: Also, if the omitted previous job is somehow in conflict with the new job (ie: if they're in the same industry and NDAs or non-compete clauses are involved) then it might look shady that you omitted it.  Not necessarily incriminating, but it might raise some eyebrows.